# Imputing multiple columns in R using mutate_at

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a large medical data frame that I want to use for ML. As such, I have to impute missing values. For the continus variables I would like to put the median value, like so:

```
dat$First_Wbc <- ifelse(is.na(dat$First_Wbc), median2(dat$First_Wbc), dat$First_Wbc)
```

I want to create a code using mutate_at that would do the same as the code I provided above, but for multiple variables at a time. I know it's possible but so far I haven't been able to format it correctly.
Can you please help me?

Note: median2() is a function identical to median() but it ignores the missing values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base R solution:

```
dat[,sapply(dat, is.numeric)] <- lapply(dat[,sapply(dat, is.numeric)], 
                                        function(x){
                                         x <- ifelse(is.na(x), median(x, na.rm  = TRUE), x)
                                          }
                                        )
```

Tidyverse using mutate_if:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  mutate_if(is.numeric, funs(replace(., is.na(.), median(., na.rm = TRUE))))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can select columns by position :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate_at(2:4, ~replace(., is.na(.), median2(.)))
```

Or by the range of columns

```
df %>% mutate_at(vars(a:d), ~replace(., is.na(.), median2(.)))
```

Or using a specific pattern in the column names.

```
df %>% mutate_at(vars(starts_with('col')), ~replace(., is.na(.), median2(.)))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `mutate_if` with `na.aggregate`

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
df %>% 
   mutate_if(is.numeric, na.aggregate, FUN = median)
```

Answer (score 1):

Speaking of tidy solutions I really like the [`naniar`](https://naniar.njtierney.com/) package, it provides many useful methods for working with missing data.

E.g., here to impute medians in all numeric columns you could do:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(naniar)

df %>%
  impute_median_if(is.numeric)
```

More added values comes with `impute_median_all()`, `impute_mean_if()` and many great missing data visualizations.

Comment: Excellent!! Best solution here. Easily extensible with dplyr::group_by and selected multiple columns using the .vars argument in naniar::impute_mean_at()